# Class specification, alternative to inheritance?

Tags: java, inheritance, uml, diagram, specifications

I need your advices and suggestions for the best specification of my classes. 
A Leader has a team of Persons, and each Person can be part of many leaders team. A leader cannot be part of any other team.

Which solution would be better ? If you have another alternative, I would be more than grateful,
(I am working on JAVA Application with JPA)

UML diagram : [image]

Thank you very much

EDIT : I thought I would explain my problem much better with this example, but actually I don't think so, here is the orginal problem : 
[UML specification : Do I need inheritance?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31458978/uml-specification-do-i-need-inheritance)

Comment: Can a Person lead many teams? Do you track the past and future membership in Teams? Can a Person give leadership responsibility to someone else and join a Team? Does a Team have an identity, name or any other properties? Are you aware that each list is duplicating an association end?

Comment: A person can lead only one team, yes it's possible de track past and future membership in Teams, a Leader is always a leader et can't join team, the team doesn't have absolutely any propriety, thank you very much.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Most teams have an identity you cannot capture in your model. It may be there is no requirement for that now, but what if there is one tomorrow? Modeling reality tends to make a model more durable because you won't have to completely redo your model when requirements become clearer or change. For this reason, I recommend you make the model more like the real world.

With that said, I think you may be missing some things:

- Each Team (typically) has a Leader and a set of Members
- A Person plays a Role
- A Role (in your case) can be that of a Leader or a Member

Also, use association end names. Assuming you're using a real UML tool, your model already contains unnamed properties that already represent lists, so why not name them and use them instead of duplicating them?

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer, but for my application, the team has absolutely any properties, and I won't use it in the future (that's why I haven't specified it in my diagram)

Comment: It's very odd to ignore something that is so prominently stated in the problem domain. Is this a toy example? What does your software do for a user?

Comment: Yes this a toy example (and actually I think is a bad example that I have made), I thought it would explain my problem better: here is the real problem : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31458978/uml-specification-do-i-need-inheritance Thank you very much

Answer (score 0):

I would come up with the following:
[image]

- A `Leader` is a `Person`.
- A `Leader` can have an arbitrary number of `Teams`
- A `Team` has exactly one `Leader`
- A `Team` is composed of (an arbitrary number) of `Person`s
- A `Person` can be in an arbitrary number of `Teams`

(the two last bullet points derived from the `Composition` without multiplicity)

As you can see UML is pretty much straight forward in what it can express.

Comment: Using subclassing for roles can be dangerous. What if the requirements change and a Person also must be able to play other roles as well? It reminds me of what Clinton said. It depends on what the definition of "is" is. 

Comment: @JimL. I guess none of the answers here is perfect in any way. But lots of them give your head the bang into another useful direction :-)

Comment: I'm afraid I don't understand your comment.

Comment: I mean that I haven't specified Team class in my UML diagram because, in my application, a team don't have any properties (no name, no attribute) and I won't use it in my application. There is not another alternative without using Team class?

Comment: Well, you can put properties inside `Person` and `Leader` and apply constraints. But a `Team` class (it has no properties except those from the associated classes) clearly simplifies the whole thing.