# UML specification : Do I need inheritance?

Tags: java, jpa, inheritance, uml, subclassing

Here's my application : the purpose is to add records based on errors (but not all errors will result in adding a new record, only the Main Errors).
Every session has many errors, then an internal service will manage this errors to know which are the Main Errors (and which are the 'small' errors, I mean the implied or related or attached to this Main Error).

UML Diagram : [image]

So I need your help and suggestions about my UML Diagram, do you think that is the best approach? do I really need the subclassing here (or maybe just putting two different classes Error and MainError would be better) ?

- So every Main error has a list of its related errors
- a Main Error cannot be part of another MainError's list
- an error can be associated to many Main Error
- I am working on Java application with JPA
- A record is associated with only one MainError and obviously many errors(as every MainError has a list of errors)

Thank you very much

Comment: This would be far easier for everyone to reason about if you would stop using lists in addition to association end properties. Each association end with max cardinality > 1 is already a collection in UML.

Comment: Your diagram doesn't match your text. You said a session has many errors, some of which will be categorized as main errors. The association should therefore connect to the superclass.

Comment: Is your real question how to express bullet 2 in UML?

Comment: Thanks Jim for your answers, sorry for the lists (which are duplicating the association end properties), I shouldn't put them in UML diagram.
The association should connect to the superclass Error ? because I was thinking it's better to connect it to MainError, and as every MainError has a list of Errors, it would be like linking Session to Error, Am I wrong? thanks

Comment: Can you revise your diagram? You should make it match your problem statements. I think part of the problem may be that you are trying to optimize too early.

Comment: Is it correct to say that a session will produce many errors, and something will later analyze them and decide which is the main problem and which are subordinate problems providing details?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think the following diagram would satisfy and restate your requirements clearly.

[image: UML analysis diagram]

What this expresses is:

- A `Session` encounters zero or more `Errors`
- An `Error` is encountered in one `Session`
- An `Error` must be an instance of one and only one of its subclasses ("complete" means an instance must be an instance of a subclass; "disjoint" means an instance cannot be multiply classified, which is impossible in Java anyway.)
- A `Main Error` causes zero or more `Subordinate Errors`
- A `Subordinate Error` is caused by zero or more `Main Errors`

What is implied is that every `Error` is initially created as an `Unclassified Error` and later classified into either a `Main Error` or a `Subordinate Error`.

I didn't bother to model `Record`, as it is far too nebulous and adds nothing to the discussion.

If you were to implement this model, the association ends would undergo a name change that retains semantics while becoming normalLookingCamelCaseForJava. Here are the name changes:

- `encounters` would become `encounteredErrors` and be of type `List<Error>`
- `encountered in` would become `encounteringSession` of type `Session`
- `causes` would become `causedSubordinateErrors` of type `List<SubordinateError>`
- `caused by` would become `causingMainErrors` of type `List<MainError>`

In JPA you could map all the error classes to one table with a discriminator, which will make the reclassification much more performant. (See [changing entity type in JPA](http://www.e-zest.net/blog/changing-entity-type-in-jpa/) for an idea of how you might do so.) Note that you might want to map many-to-many associations to separate relational database tables. That's a separate discussion, though.

Comment: Very very interesting!! THANK YOU very much, so I have few questions : 1) Record will be then linked to MainError and not to Error right ? (Record *-1 MainError)   2) Error will be abstract and I will not have Error table obviously? 3) What is the real purpose of UnclassifiedError? I call the service getError(Session) then I have all the errors, I declare them as UnclassifiedError, then I call the service manageErrors(UnclassifiedErrors) which will create the MainErrors with list of subordinateErrors and then I persist in the database MainErrors and SubordinateErrors right?

Comment: 1) Correct. 2) In Java `Error` should be abstract, but in UML, the {covering} constraint is equivalent. In JPA, by default, you get one table with a discriminator. I would expect that table would be called `Error`. 3) `UnclassifiedError` is what you create when you don't yet know what it is. Yes, your `manageErrors()` could work, although a better name might be `classifyErrors()`, or something that hints at analysis and classification.

Comment: If you find my answer the most helpful, please press the button to accept it.

Comment: I really appreciate your help!! As you are so kind, I have few more questions 1) UnclassifiedErrors will not be persistant in DB and in DAO layer, I will not have any method related to UnClassifiedErrors right? 2) Without UnClassifiedErrors, my approach was to call getError(Session), to have all Errors, to declare them as objects, then call classifyErrors(Errors), which will create the MainErrors with list of its related errors, then I persist in DB all the Errors (which are not Main) then I persist the MainErrors so I duplicate nothing, I guess it's better to use UnclassifiedEr to avoid this?

Comment: 3) Last important question, Session would be related to Error ? how I can manage that in JPA ? in Session class I declare List<Error> ? because as I see, to know which are the Errors of each session, I have access to its MainErrors and then the subordinate errors of these MainErrors (Anyway, I more interested to know which are the MainErrors of a session than its Errors). THANK YOU VERY MUCH

Answer (score 0):

Discuss the diagram yourself. What is an `Error`? It just consists of an `ErrorID`. This is not much of an info. So why create such a class? I would not see any reason for it. So when there is no reason, why create it? And there you are. It's superfluous. You can probably go with an association from `MainError` to self. Then you can rename `MainError` to be simply `Error`.